# Inline functions in React cause re-renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read in an article that if you have some code like:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Child
        onClick={() => console.log('You clicked!')}
     />
    );
  }
}
```

`Child` will be re-rendered every time `Parent` re-renders, even if there's no change in its props, only because the `onClick` function is inline and so it creates a new reference on every render.

However, even after moving that function outside of `render()`, `Child` re-rendered.. so what am i missing here?

In addition, that article also mentioned that inline functions increases a React app's memory footprint, since a new function reference is created on each render. Is that true? Doesn't JS have some sort of automatic garbage collection?

Comment: just out of curiosity... can you share a link to the article?

Comment: Sure: https://medium.com/technogise/journey-of-improving-react-app-performance-by-10x-9195d4b483d4

Comment: I would suggest reading this: https://dmitripavlutin.com/dont-overuse-react-usecallback/, particularly the `The purpose of useCallback()` section

Comment: Look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-babbage-w495w... Child components always rerender when parents rerender, even when no props are used at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things, what you have posted only works for Class components, and as to why it works with Class components is that you are creating a callback function and binding it to the *instance* of the component, therefore each render of the component, it is the *same* callback function instance being used.

More reading on this https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/ under "Why don’t we need to bind ‘this’ for Arrow functions?"

For a function component, it's different, there is no class instance, you can use the `useCallback` hook that will memoize a callback, given a set of dependencies remain the same.

As someone pointed out in the comments you should only really aim to memoize callbacks etc though when they will prevent rerenders of large/deep children

Comment: Thanks! What about the question regarding the memory footprint?